# Find Serial and parallel percentage of code

Tags: parallel-processing, cpu, parallelism-amdahl

If I know the job completion time of a 2 processor system and of a 4 processor system, how do i calculate the time taken(Ts) by a 1 processor system. I want to know this so I can find the serial percentage of any given code using the equation

```
Ts/Tp = 1/(S+[(1-S)/N])
```

where S is serial percentage of code and N number of processors

Answer (score 0):

I think time taken would be product of JobCompletionTime and number of processors;
jobCompletionTime*n(no of processors);